# Bulbul bird beak or Bulbul bird's beak?

Tags: possessives, modifiers, noun-phrases

What is the correct option of these two following options? 
I'm talking about the beak of the Bulbul birds.

1. > Bulbul bird beak
2. > Bulbul bird**'s** beak

Comment: Neither of those is a sentence.  Please provide the full sentence you are considering.

Answer (score 4):

Whether you use a possessive with apostrophe-s ("Bulbul bird's beak") or a noun adjunct ("Bulbul bird beak") depends on how you wish the phrase to be used. If you are describing a beak that belongs to the bird or is of the bird, then use the first one. If you are generally modifying the noun's meaning, especially if referring to Bulbul birds' beaks in general, then it is better to use the second. Often you will find that either option is acceptable. If I am talking about a particular Bulbul bird, then it is better to use the possessive, for example "I like to stroke my Bulbul bird's beak." If I am talking about the concept of the beak, especially as it relates to any Bulbul bird, either option is fine, for example: "Few beaks are as fascinating as the Bulbul bird beak." or "Few beaks are as fascinating as the Bulbul bird's beak."